# Wike does not open in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: software-installation, python, 22.10

I am using Ubuntu Unity 22.10. I installed the Wikipedia reader Wike with the command

```
sudo apt install wike
```

However, when I try to open Wike, it does not load. If run from terminal, the output is,

```
$ wike
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/wike", line 47, in <module>
    from wike import application
  File "/usr/share/wike/wike/application.py", line 29, in <module>
    from wike.window import Window
  File "/usr/share/wike/wike/window.py", line 26, in <module>
    from wike.header import HeaderBar
  File "/usr/share/wike/wike/header.py", line 29, in <module>
    from wike.search import SearchEntry
  File "/usr/share/wike/wike/search.py", line 26, in <module>
    from wike import wikipedia
  File "/usr/share/wike/wike/wikipedia.py", line 20, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: I have created a bug report in Launchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wike/+bug/1993744 If you can reproduce it, and use this software regularly, consider marking it as "Affects me", so that the bug gets more attention. This is a Debian packaging bug (missing dependencies) and NOT an upstream bug.

Comment: Great catch of the bug!

Comment: About the close vote: This question is not a bug report, neither it is about a development version. This is about how users can fix the issue.

Comment: It's about both the bug (that you properly filed) AND the workaround (that folks need to know about). The close vote is not intended to disparage the great question nor your excellent troubleshooting -- it merely expresses that *further* discussion in AskUbuntu is not constructive because it's a real bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to manually install `python3-requests`, which should have been a dependency.

```
sudo apt install python3-requests
```